# How can I list the Active Directory user attributes from a linux computer?

Tags: linux, active-directory, attributes

How can I list the Active directory user attributes from a Linux computer? 
The Linux computer is already joined to the domain. I can use 'getent' to get the user and group information, but it does not display the complete active directory user attributes.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `ldapsearch` to query an AD Server. For example, the following query will displya all attributes of all the users in the domain:

```
ldapsearch   -x -h adserver.domain.int -D "user@domain.int" -W -b "cn=users,dc=domain,dc=int"
```

Command options explained:

- -x use simple authentication (as opposed to SASL)
- -h  your AD server
- -D   the DN to bind to the directory.  In other words, the user you are authenticating with.
- -W Prompt for the password. The password should match what is in your directory for the the binddn (-D).  Mutually exclusive from -w.
- -b  The starting point for the search

More info: http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=ldapsearch&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.0-Release&format=html

Answer (score 7):

A much simpler command is

```
id myuser@MYDOMAIN
```

For this command to work, your machine must have already joined the domain; you can verify that via

```
realm list
```

Answer (score 1):

If the OS is integrated with Active directory, then simply running "id" command should be sufficient to list the AD groups assigned to the user.

The commands like id/gid will give results just the way they do when OS is not integrated with AD.

PFB the sample:

```
[oracle@wlsserver1~]$ id s_dhan
uid=1356186729(s_dhan) gid=1356000513(domain users) groups=1356000513(domain users),1356162912(linux-skl-prod-login),1356177219(linux-tom-dv-login),....
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just use the groups command:

```
# groups <user_ID>
```